# Is there a way to forward all assignment operators (+=, *=, etc.) to implicitly use an overridden direct assignment operator (=)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, wrapper

I know "forwarding" is an unrelated concept in C++11 (as in "perfect forwarding") but it's the first word that comes to mind for me for describing the problem.

I'm overriding the `operator=` in a wrapper class `Proxy`,

```
template<typename T>
class Proxy
{
public:
    enum class State
    {
        NEVER_SET = 0,
        SET
    };
    operator const T& () const
    {
        if ( _state != State::SET )
        {
            throw std::domain_error{ "using unset data" };
        }
        return _data;
    }
    Proxy<T>& operator=(const T& val)
    {
        _data = val;
        _state = State::SET;
        return (*this);
    }
private:
    T _data;
    State _state = State::NEVER_SET;
};
```

but find myself also needing to add:

```
    Proxy<T>& operator+=(const T& val)
    {
        _data = (*this) + val;
        _state = State::SET;
        return (*this);
    }
    Proxy<T>& operator-=(const T& val)
    {
        _data = (*this) - val;
        _state = State::SET;
        return (*this);
    }
    Proxy<T>& operator*=(const T& val)
    {
        _data = (*this) * val;
        _state = State::SET;
        return (*this);
    }
    Proxy<T>& operator/=(const T& val)
    {
        _data = (*this) / val;
        _state = State::SET;
        return (*this);
    }
    // ...and so on.
```

Is there a trick to "forwarding" all assignment operators (`+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `>>=`, `<<=`, `|=`, `&=`, `^=`) so that I don't have to define them? That is, a way to make

```
Proxy<double> x = 7;
Proxy<double> y = 43;
x += y;
```

automatically "unravel" to

```
Proxy<double> x = 7;
Proxy<double> y = 43;
x = x + y; // cast operator converts x and y to double, then direct assigns sum,
           // therefore no += needing definition in Proxy<T>
```

Comment: You can do the reverse (i.e., define `+=` and let `+` be automatically generated) with [`boost::operators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/utility/operators.htm).

Comment: Hm, but it seems currently I don't need `+` to be generated, because the cast operation conveniently defines `+` for me where the underlying data type `T` has the appropriate operator. I was hoping for a technique that lets me define only the direct assignment operator.

Comment: @AndrewCheong why don't you have the body of `operator+=` be `*this = *this + val;`, that achieves the aim of unraveling `x += y` to `x = x + y`.

Comment: (I don't think this is a great idea as it is more operations than implementing `operator+=` without referring to `operator=`, but it is what you requested!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the CRTP, but if you aim to only have an explicit `=` in your Proxy class, you'll need to provide some access to types for which the other operators are already available.  Put another way, you can't say `a1 = a2 + a3` if you've defined how to assign but not how to add.  I address this below by expecting a `get()` function that exposes some state that can be operated on.  It's far more typical (and probably practical) to explicitly define e.g. `+=` then have `+` defined in terms of it....

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Implied_Ops
{
    T operator+(const T& rhs) const
    {
        return rhs.get() + static_cast<const T*>(this)->get();
    }

    T& operator+=(const T& rhs)
    {
        return static_cast<T&>(*this) = operator+(rhs);
    }
};

struct X : Implied_Ops<X>
{
    X(int n) : n_(n) { }
    X& operator=(const X& rhs) { n_ = rhs.n_; return *this; }
    int get() const { return n_; }
    int n_;
};

int main()
{
    X x { 10 };
    X x2 = x + x;
    X x3 = x + x2;
    std::cout << x.n_ << ' ' << x2.n_ << ' ' << x3.n_ << '\n';
}
```

Another approach that shouldn't be overlooked is macros....

Comment: To make sure I understand you correctly, if I only want `+` to be possible for types `T` which already have such an operator, _e.g._ `double`, `int`, etc. then I wouldn't need to define `Implied_Ops` at all, correct? (But I find the suggestion valuable nonetheless.) Or, am I misunderstanding.

Comment: Wrong... you need `Implied_Ops`, but just don't need to define how to add/divide/multiple/etc types like `double`, `int`.  Other user-defined-types will need the minimal set of operations from which you define your extended set supported by `Proxy`.  Either way, you *extend* T's support for `+`, `-` etc operations to `Proxy` using `Implied_Ops` / CRTP as illustrated, making `_data` accessible with `get()`. In your case, you'd also add `_state = State::SET;` to `operator=`'s definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes with CRTP.

```
template<class D>
struct plus_equals {
  template<class Rhs>
  D& operator+=(Rhs&& rhs){
    D*self=static_cast<D*>(this);
    self->_data = (*self)+std::forward<Rhs>(rhs);
    self->_state= State::SET;
    return *self;
  }
};
```

then inherit your class `Foo` publically from `plus_equals<Foo>`.

Of course you need to write that boilerplate for each operator, so it does not help much for one type.